# Pandas: conditionally concatenate original columns with a string

Tags: python, pandas

**INPUT>df1**

```
    ColumnA ColumnB
     A1       NaN
     A1A2     NaN
     A3       NaN
```

What I tried to do is to change column B's value conditionally,
based on iteration of checking ColumnA, adding remarks to column B.
The previous value of column B shall be kept after new string is added.

In sample dataframe, what I want to do would be

- If ColumnA contains A1. If so, add string "A1" to Column B (without cleaning all previous value.)
- If ColumnA contains A2. If so, add string "A2" to Column B (without cleaning all previous value.)

**OUTPUT>df1**

```
    ColumnA ColumnB
     A1       A1
     A1A2     A1_A2
     A3       NaN
```

I have tried the following codes but not working well.
Could anyone give me some advices? Thanks.

```
df1['ColumnB'] = np.where(df1['ColumnA'].str.contains('A1'), df1['ColumnB']+"_A1",df1['ColumnB'])
df1['ColumnB'] = np.where(df1['ColumnA'].str.contains('A2'), df1['ColumnB']+"_A2",df1['ColumnB'])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot add or append strings to `np.nan`. That means you would always need to check if any position in your `ColumnB` is still a `np.nan` or already a string to properly set its new value. If all you want to do is to work with text you could initialize your `ColumnB` with empty strings and append selected string pieces from `ColumnA` as:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

I = pd.DataFrame({'ColA': ['A1', 'A1A2', 'A2', 'A3']})
I['ColB'] = ''
I.loc[I.ColA.str.contains('A1'), 'ColB'] += 'A1'
print(I)

I.loc[I.ColA.str.contains('A2'), 'ColB'] += 'A2'
print(I)
```

The output is:

```
   ColA ColB
0    A1   A1
1  A1A2   A1
2    A2     
3    A3     
   ColA  ColB
0    A1    A1
1  A1A2  A1A2
2    A2    A2
3    A3
```

Note: this is a very verbose version as an example.

Comment: Solved! As you mentioned, the problem occured due to appending strings to np.nan

Answer (score 3):

One way using `pandas.Series.str.findall` with `join`:

```
key = ["A1", "A2"]
df["ColumnB"] = df["ColumnA"].str.findall("|".join(key)).str.join("_")
print(df)
```

Output:

```
  ColumnA ColumnB
0      A1      A1
1    A1A2   A1_A2
2      A3
```